# Trouble Installing Plone on Solaris 11

Tags: plone, solaris

I am new to Plone and Solaris - I'm attempting to install Plone 5 on Solaris 11.  Seems to be hanging up on the Zope install.  Here is the install.log:

```
Detailed installation log
Starting at Wed Oct 14 11:41:13 AKDT 2015
The directory '/home/dotasdis/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/dotasdis/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Processing ./packages/zc.buildout-2.4.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>=8.0 in /opt/plone/zinstance/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from zc.buildout==2.4.3)
Installing collected packages: zc.buildout
  Running setup.py install for zc.buildout
Successfully installed zc.buildout-2.4.3
/opt/plone/zinstance/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Creating directory '/opt/plone/zinstance/parts'.
Creating directory '/opt/plone/zinstance/develop-eggs'.
Not found: /opt/plone/buildout-cache/downloads/dist/ZODB3/
Not found: /opt/plone/buildout-cache/downloads/dist/ZODB3/
Getting distribution for 'ZODB3==3.10.5'.
gcc: cg: No such file or directory
gcc: unrecognized option '-Qoption'
gcc: unrecognized option '-KPIC'
gcc: language O5 not recognized
gcc: language O5 not recognized
error: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/gcc/4.5/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
An error occurred when trying to install ZODB3 3.10.5. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing.
  Getting section instance.
  Initializing section instance.
  Installing recipe plone.recipe.zope2instance.
  Getting distribution for 'ZODB3==3.10.5'.
Error: Couldn't install: ZODB3 3.10.5
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Unified Installer? I am not sure Solaris is anymore on supported platforms. The most exotic was BSD last time I checked. However there is no reason Plone itself should not work as it is standard Python + UNIX software. Maybe trying doing Buildout based installation from scratch?

Comment: That looks like it's trying to use a version of Solaris Studio compiler instead of gcc, as those are Solaris Studio `cc` options, and rather recent ones, too, from the `-Qoption`, which was added in Studio 12.3 only a few years ago.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E54439/cc-1.html#scrolltoc for the Studio 12.4 options.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it those suggestions a try.  Appreciate it!

Comment: The comment on cc/gcc comment was spot on.  I installed the Solaris Studio and the install proceeds but now is failing here ...

Generated script '/home/dotasdis/Plone/zinstance/bin/plonectl'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dotasdis/Plone/zinstance/bin/zopepy", line 261, in <module>
    exec(_val)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ld.so.1: python2.7: fatal: relocation error: file /home/dotasdis/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/lxml-3.4.4-py2.7-solaris-2.11-sun4u.32bit.egg/lxml/etree.so: symbol __xmlStructuredErrorContext: referenced symbol not found

Comment: I was able to get Plone-4.3.7 installed on Solaris 11.  For some reason 5.0 had issues - at least I was able to get it installed.  Thanks Mikko and Andrew for the response - much appreciated!

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you'll need to build Python "C" packages with the same compiler as was used to build Python. So, if you want to use the GNU build tools, you'll probably need to build a Python with them. The Unified Installer has a --build-python flag that may help with that.